# Binomial and series with 2 coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I would be very grateful if you would help me with this question:

Find the sum :
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k}
$$

Answer (score 3):

By symmetry of the binomial coefficients, *twice* this sum is the sum from $k=0$ to $k=2n$, that is, $2^{2n}$, minus the center coefficient, that is, ${2n\choose n}$.

Answer (score 3):

First thing that you have to notice is the expression is somewhat similar to
$$ (x + y)^N = \sum_{\nu = 0}^N \binom{N}{\nu}x^\nu y^{N - \nu}. $$

If $x = y = 1$ and $N = 2n$ then this becomes
\begin{align*} 
2^{2n} &= 
\sum_{\nu = 0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{\nu} \\ & = 
\sum_{\nu = 0}^{n} \binom{2n}{\nu} + \sum_{\nu = n + 1}^{2n} \binom{2n}{\nu} \\ &=
\sum_{\nu = 0}^{n} \binom{2n}{\nu} + \sum_{\nu = n + 1}^{2n} \binom{2n}{2n - \nu} \\ &=
\sum_{\nu = 0}^{n} \binom{2n}{\nu} + \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \binom{2n}{k} \\ &=
2\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{2n}{k} - \binom{2n}{n}.
\end{align*}
Therefore you get
$$\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{2n}{k} = \frac{2^{2n} + \binom{2n}{n}}{2}.$$